# MySQL INSERT else if exists UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I'm building a config table with two columns, config_name and config_value. I insert multiple rows in one statement:

```
INSERT INTO ".$dbPrefix."config (config_name,config_value) VALUES
             ('domain','$domain'),
             ('forest_root','$fr_if'),
             ('userGroup','$userGroup'),
             ('adminGroup','$adminGroup');
```

The config_name column is a primary key. How would I change this statement to automatically update the config_value if the config_name already exists?

Comment: read: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try this syntax:

```
INSERT INTO table (field) VALUES (value) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE field=value
```

Docs can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Comment: This is what I was looking at but  I am updating only 1 field with multiple values being searched and updated within it (config_name)

Comment: Actually after a bit of playing around I've managed to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do an upsert, and I think this may help:
http://database-programmer.blogspot.com/2009/06/approaches-to-upsert.html