# Condition-driven INSERT and UPDATE in a single query

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance

I have a MySQL table with the following fields:

1. ID
2. PHONE
3. NAME
4. CITY
5. COUNTRY

Using PHP, I am reading a comma separated dump of values off a text document, parsing the values and inserting records to the table. For reference, here's the code:

```
 <?php

    // Includes
        require_once 'PROJdbconn.php';

    // Read comma-separated text file
        $arrindx = 0;
        $i = 0;

        $filehandle = fopen(PROJCDUMPPATH.PROJCDUMPNAME,"rb");
        while (!feof($filehandle)){
            $parts = explode(',', fgets($filehandle));
            $contnames[$arrindx] = $parts['0'];
            $contnumbers[$arrindx] = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/','',$parts['1']);
            $arrindx += 1;
        }
        fclose($filehandle);
        $arrindx -= 1;
        $filehandle = NULL;
        $parts = NULL;

    // Build SQL query
        $sql = "INSERT INTO Contact_table (PHONE, NAME) VALUES ";
        for ($i = 0; $i < $arrindx; ++$i){
            $sql .= "('".$contnumbers[$i]."', '".$contnames[$i]."'),";
        }
        $i = NULL;
        $arrindx = NULL;
        $contnames = NULL;
        $contnumbers = NULL;
        $sql = substr($sql,0,strlen($sql)-1).";";

    // Connect to MySQL database
        $connect = dbconn(PROJHOST,PROJDB,PROJDBUSER,PROJDBPWD);

    // Execute SQL query
        $query = $connect->query($sql);
        $sql = NULL;
        $query = NULL;

    // Close connection to MySQL database
        $connect = NULL;



    ?>
```

Now, this code, as you can see, blindly dumps all records into the table. However, I need to modify the code logic as such:

```
Read text file and parse records into arrays (already doing)
For each record in text file
    Check if PHONE exists in the table
    If yes,
        For each field in the text file record
            If text file field != NULL
                Update corresponding field in table
            Else
                Skip
    If no,
        INSERT record (already doing)
```

I apologize if the logic isn't terribly clear, feel free to ask me if any aspect confuses you. So, I understand this logic would involve an insane number of SELECT, UPDATE, and INSERT queries, depending on the number of fields (I intend to add more fields in future) and records. Is there any way to either somehow morph them into a single query or leastwise optimize the code by minimizing the number of queries?

Comment: I think you have to take a look on MySQL documentation for INSERT - especially clause "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE". Of course if you'll use it you have to make the phone number column unique.

Comment: I did consider the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE method. However, I need to run the condition on individual fields within the record found to be duplicate. Only those fields are to be updated where I have a NON-NULL value to offer. For example if an entry already exists for phone number 123456, I wouldn't want to overwrite the entire record; only those fields where I have a real value to replace it with.

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do is called an "upsert" (update/insert).

[MySQL INSERT else if exists UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8017087/mysql-insert-else-if-exists-update)